# Python ImportError: reload() module not in sys.modules... but it is?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am having the strangest problem I think that I've ever encountered.

Using py.test with Python 2.7, I get the following ultra-weirdness:

```
        print('draftin_a_flask.draftin_a_flask' in sys.modules)
>       reload(draftin_a_flask)
E       ImportError: reload(): module draftin_a_flask.draftin_a_flask not in sys.modules

tests/test_draftin_a_flask.py:197: ImportError
------------------------------------- Captured stdout -------------------------------------
True
```

Fact:

- According to the print statement, `draftin_a_flask.draftin_a_flask` is in fact in sys.modules
- According to the error thrown on the reload statement the line directly after, jk! no it's not.
- As a result I'm insanely confused, because wat.

What in the world could I possibly have going wrong here?

### Edit:

It appears that the offending change I've made has something to do with the following in my `tox.ini`

```
[pytest]
python_functions=test_
python_files=*.py
norecursedirs = .tox .git docs
```

I remove those lines, and voila! We work. Put 'em back and reload problem. I'm digging some more into this.

### Edit #2:

It appears the `python_files=*.py` line is the culprit. But **why**?

You can check out the code from here: https://github.com/waynew/draftin-a-flask and add the following lines to `tox.ini`

```
[pytest]
python-files=*.py
```

To observe the behavior

Comment: How did you import the module the first time?

Comment: `from draftin_a_flask import draftin_a_flask`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary just added some more (pertinent) info

Comment: I don't have an answer but I know that py.test is monkey patching a lot of core python mechanism and that "reload" is one of them